Purpose of return value in non-exception overloads
Boost ASIO usually has a duplicated API when one function may throw an exception and another one does not. For example:
void close();
boost::system::error_code close(
    boost::system::error_code & ec);

or
void shutdown(
    shutdown_type what);
boost::system::error_code shutdown(
    shutdown_type what,
    boost::system::error_code & ec);

My question is: why does the second version of the function (which doesn't throw an exception) use a return value (boost::system::error_code) although it already takes a variable to indicate an error via input parameter (boost::system::error_code & ec)?
As I can see from the Boost ASIO examples the return value usually is ignored.
Update 0: @Persixty pointed out that Boost ASIO has differences in API across different versions:

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/shutdown.html ;
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/shutdown.html .

In other words, the modern version of the library should return void.
I write should because on my host (Ubuntu 24.04) I use Boost ASIO v1.83, but it still returns an error code:
/usr/include/boost/asio/detail/reactive_socket_service.hpp

  // Disable sends or receives on the socket.
  boost::system::error_code shutdown(base_implementation_type& impl,
      socket_base::shutdown_type what, boost::system::error_code& ec)
  {
    socket_ops::shutdown(impl.socket_, what, ec);

    BOOST_ASIO_ERROR_LOCATION(ec);
    return ec;
  }

Or:
/usr/include/boost/asio/detail/win_iocp_socket_service.hpp

  // Disable sends or receives on the socket.
  boost::system::error_code shutdown(base_implementation_type& impl,
      socket_base::shutdown_type what, boost::system::error_code& ec)
  {
    socket_ops::shutdown(impl.socket_, what, ec);
    return ec;
  }


I see two possible reasons. (1) Differentiate the overload, this is a must since a return type alone won't do it. (2) A poor person's nodsicard. It forces one to store the return code while still allowing if ( ... == boost::system::some_code ) { do_stuff(); } which looks kind idiomatic.

To help with context, Is the question about these overloads? https://live.boost.org/doc/libs/1_86_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_socket/shutdown/overload1.html and https://live.boost.org/doc/libs/1_86_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_socket/shutdown/overload2.html

@StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica OP is asking why there is a return type when there is already a second input parameter not that why there is a second parameter when there is already a return type. You seem to be answering the latter which isn't the question.

@Alan - I'm not answering anything since I posted a comment speculating with the OP, not an answer. Now my second idea, most definitely, muses in the other direction. I wonder how you could have missed that.

@Alan I think these are two sides of same coin. Returning (possibly modified) input is kind of idiomatic in functional programming. even in form T* modify(T* arg, other_t otherarg) which is so abundant in ISO C library and varous utility API.

@Persixty, thank you for the clarification! Please see updates in the topic.

There's none. It is inherently inconsistent because it cannot be used for non-void operations.
Asio's developer has realized this and deprecated the return value. If you compile with BOOST_ASIO_NO_DEPRECATED then the functions will return void:
  BOOST_ASIO_SYNC_OP_VOID close(boost::system::error_code& ec)
  {
    impl_.get_service().close(impl_.get_implementation(), ec);
    BOOST_ASIO_SYNC_OP_VOID_RETURN(ec);
  }

Where config.hpp contains:
// Helper macros to manage transition away from error_code return values.
#if defined(BOOST_ASIO_NO_DEPRECATED)
# define BOOST_ASIO_SYNC_OP_VOID void
# define BOOST_ASIO_SYNC_OP_VOID_RETURN(e) return
#else // defined(BOOST_ASIO_NO_DEPRECATED)
# define BOOST_ASIO_SYNC_OP_VOID boost::system::error_code
# define BOOST_ASIO_SYNC_OP_VOID_RETURN(e) return e
#endif // defined(BOOST_ASIO_NO_DEPRECATED)

The deprecation stems from 2017 with the initial merge of NetworkingTS compatibility changes: https://github.com/boostorg/asio/commit/b60e92b13ef68dfbb9af180d76eae41d22e19356

Amazing, I could only dream that @sehe comes to my topic and provides me with the answer! Before, I thought that you expert in boost parsers, but now I see that your experience is much wider! Thanks!
